# Calibration of stochastic volatility models

Tags: stochastic

Which are good references to know about different calibration methods for stochastic volatility models such as Heston? I know that there are a lot of way of carrying this task out and I was just wondering if there is something like a survey of some work and project done about.

Comment: Take a look at the 3rd paper [here](http://www.jaeckel.org), the one about ultra sparse grids for slv calibration.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at [Stochastic Volatility Modeling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1482244063) by Lorenzo Bergomi.